# Add decimal position to long

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I have a long value and I would like to convert it to a decimal of 3.

Sample values:
324
4353
53463

If a value has a length of 3, those numbers are the decimals like: 324 should be 0.324.

If it has 4 positions of more, the last 3 numbers are the decimals, example: 4353 should be 4.353 and 53463 should be 53.463.

What would be the best way to do this... Should I convert it to String and use string operations to add the . or is there an easier way to do this (doesn't seem right)?

Comment: hm. `(double)x / 1000.0` ?

Comment: You haven't specified the form in which you need the result, which depends on what you want to do with it. Do you want a string `"0.324"`, Or do you want that sequence of characters to be printed? Or a floating-point value? Or an integer value that your code will *interpret* as the numeric value 0.324?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The `(double)` isn't even necessary since you're dividing by a `double`. `x/1000.0` works fine.

Comment: @Kevin I wasn't sure which side to have `double`, so I made them both :)

Comment: Since `double` has no concept of decimal places, you must be converting to a string. Split the number `long n` into two parts with `long i = n / 1000` and `long d = n % 1000` and then create a string with `sprintf` (or print it directly with `printf`) using those two parts, with width and padding specifiers as appropriate, separated by a `'.'`. But this isn't a "gimme the codez" site.

Comment: ... oops, why the C tag? Arduino is not C.

Comment: @WeatherVane But youve got to write code in some language.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Good point -- but `324 / 1000.0` will give you a floating-point value that's a close approximation of `0.324`, and that will print that way with the right format specifier. (The stored value will most likely be something like `0.324000000000000010214051826551440171897411346435546875`). Again, we can't really tell which method is better without more information from the OP about how the result needs to be used.

Comment: @FilipKočica you mean OP has to write the code, and Arduino is not C but its own language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a long value and I would like to convert it to a decimal of 3.

Per this and OP's other notes, its appears a *string* or print out is desired.

Nominally, the below will accomplishes this.  Note that `d` will likely have a value that is only *near* the mathematically multiple of 0.001, but not exactly.  Yet `printf()` will print a rounded value as desired.

```
long some_long = foo();
double d = some_long / 1000.0;
printf("%.3f\n", d);
```

---

But what happens when the values bits in `long` exceed the binary precision of `double`?

Print in 2 parts. Handling negative values is tricky: be sure to print the sign and use the absolute values of the most and lesser part and print leading zeros.

```
long some_long = foo();
long most = some_long / 1000;
long least = some_long % 1000;
printf("%s%ld.%03ld\n", "-" + (some_long >= 0), labs(most), labs(least));
```

[to wiki - not in it for the points]

Comment: `printf("%ld.%03ld\n", most, labs(least));` does not work for `some_long = -100;`. It prints `0.100`.

Comment: possible fix: `printf("%s%ld.%03ld\n", "-" + (some_long >= 0), labs(most), labs(least));`  can you find a more elegant solution?

Comment: @chqrlie Hmmm. Good catch - makes me think of _other_ code I've done that needs review.  As this is wiki, edit as you like.

Comment: @chux I'm trying to put your solution together in a function. How can I return the outcome of the printf? When I end the function with `return printf("%s%ld.%03ld\n", "-" + (some_long >= 0), labs(most), labs(least));` 
it returns the number of chars.

Comment: @svh1985 "How can I return the outcome of the printf?" && "it returns the number of chars" --> that is the outcome of `printf()`.  If that is not what you want , please clearly state what you want `printf()` to do.  Perhaps an example?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your entire question can be summarized as follows:

You have a `long` that you want to convert to `double` and divide by 1000.

So, as people have already explained in the comments, `x / 1000.0` should do it.

If you only want to display it with a `.`, and you do not in fact have a use for a `double`, then converting the `long` to string, prepending some zeros, and embedding the `.` character in the string should also do just fine, especially since this, being an arduino, probably does not have any internationalization concerns.  (If you did have internationalization concerns, then you'd want to go with the `double`, as your standard library would display it with either a `.` or a `,` or whatever would be right for the current culture.)

Comment: If you're going to embed the `.` in a string, there are several corner cases to consider. If the input is less than 1000, you'll need to add leading `0`s. If it's negative, you have to deal with the `-` sign.

Comment: @Keith Thompson what for. if you scale 4 decimal places in the integer 0.0056 is represented by 56. No leading zeroes needed

Comment: @KeithThompson true.

Comment: @PeterJ: I was referring to the suggestion in the last paragraph, to convert the integer to a string and then insert a `.` character. (The "prepending some zeros" clause was added after my comment.)

Comment: There is a precision issue: `double` only has 53 bits of mantissa whereas `long` may have 63 value bits.  Your solution fails on many very large `long` values.

Comment: @chqrlie true too.

Answer (score 0):

The technique is called scaling. Just treat numbers as multiplied by 10^(number of decimal places).

Example: two decimal  places: 457657856 means 4576578.56

4 decimal places 56 means 0.0056

x and y are scaled to n decimal places, w and z represent real numbers

x + y = w + z

x - y = x - z

(x * y) / 10^n = w * z

(x * 10^n) / y = w / z

Reading from the string - you have 1e10 SO topics about it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for positive and negative values:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_long_3decimals(long value) {
    char buf[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(long) / 3 + 2];
    int len = sprintf(buf, "%04ld", value);
    printf("%*s.%s\n", len - 3, buf, buf + len - 3);
}
```

Here is another one for just converting to a string with a specified number of decimals:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// assuming dest is sufficiently large
char *convert_long_decimals(char *dest, long value, int decimals) {
    int n = decimals > 0 ? decimals : 0;
    char *p = dest + sprintf(dest, "%0*ld", n + 1, value) - n;
    if (n) {
        memmove(p + 1, p, n + 1);
        *p = '.';
    }
    return dest;
}
```